# nested case in databricks using spark sql

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to use nested case in spark SQL as in the below query

```
%sql SELECT CASE WHEN 1 > 0 THEN 
CAST(CASE WHEN 2 > 0 THEN 2.0 ELSE 1.2 END AS INT)
ELSE "NOT FOUND "
```

however, I am coming across the error

```
Error in SQL statement: ParseException: 
mismatched input '1' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}(line 1, pos 17)

== SQL ==
SELECT CASE WHEN 1 > 0 THEN 
-----------------^^^
CAST(CASE WHEN 2 > 0 THEN 2.0 ELSE 1.2 END AS INT)
ELSE "NOT FOUND "
```

does databricks support nested case statement? and if yes, then please suggest what is the issue in the above code.

Comment: you forgot to `end` the case statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
spark.sql("""
SELECT  CASE WHEN 1 > 0 THEN CAST(CASE WHEN 2 > 0 THEN 2.0 ELSE 1.2 END AS INT)
        ELSE 'NOT FOUND' END AS select_case
""").show(10)

+-----------+
|select_case|
+-----------+
|          2|
+-----------+
```